# NSFileManager create symbolic link with content

Tags: objective-c, macos, symlink, nsfilemanager

I need to extract files from zip archive. Part of that files can be symbolic links. Contents of that files looks like `../../../Braintree/BraintreeUI/Public/UIColor+BTUI.h` My unzip library (ZipZap) have files properties, so I always know - is this file is a symbolic link, or it is regular file:

```
... // open and read archive, list entries
ZZArchiveEntry *entry = ... // get one entry
BOOL isSymlink = (entry.fileMode & S_IFLNK) == S_IFLNK;
```

So, if `isSymlink == YES` my task is to create symbolic link file and write archive item content to that file. I use this code:

```
NSData *fileData = [entry newDataWithError:nil]; // valid NSData, contents as described above
NSString *filePath = ... // correct and writable path
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFileType:NSFileTypeSymbolicLink};

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:fileData attributes:attributes];
```

But as result I get regular file in Finder. When I extract my archive with built-in Mac archive utility - I get correct symbolic links.

I also try this trick to change file type **after** file creation:

```
NSDictionary *original = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *newProperties = [original mutableCopy];
newProperties[NSFileType] = NSFileTypeSymbolicLink;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:newProperties ofItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

NSDictionary *updated = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

There is no errors, but original and updated dictionaries are same:

```
NSFileCreationDate = "2017-04-25 22:09:04 +0000";
NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 20;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = staff;
NSFileHFSCreatorCode = 0;
NSFileHFSTypeCode = 0;
NSFileModificationDate = "2017-04-25 22:09:04 +0000";
NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
NSFileOwnerAccountName = wind;
NSFilePosixPermissions = 420;
NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
NSFileSize = 55;
NSFileSystemFileNumber = 43896483;
NSFileSystemNumber = 16777217;
NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
```

What is the correct way to create (or update) file attributes and file type with NSFileManager, using archive `entry.fileMode` value? In my tests it was `41453`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `createSymbolicLinkAtPath:withDestinationPath:error:` to create a symbolic link, you cannot create a regular file and convert it to a link. HTH

Comment: Thank you. I take DestinationPath from fileData string, all works right as it should. (With relative path like in my question)